# GC threads waiting in the middle of collection

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance, garbage-collection

Problem: garbage collection on generation 0 takes about 1 - 1.5 seconds.
CPU usage is low 10 - 15%. 
Time in GC is high (40 - 60%). 
Promoted memory to generation 1 is relatively low (1-2 MB out of 400 MB)
Details: ASP.NET 4.5.1 site with Server GC having 16 foreground and 16 background GC threads

When looking into memory dumps (most of them are in a middle of GC) with windbg I see that all foreground GC threads are waiting for something. Here is the stack (it is same for all threads):

ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xa
KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x9a
clr!CLREventWaitHelper2+0x38
clr!CLREventWaitHelper+0x1f
clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0x70
clr!SVR::t_join::join+0x106
clr!SVR::gc_heap::plan_phase+0x9f1
clr!SVR::gc_heap::gc1+0xa6
clr!SVR::gc_heap::garbage_collect+0x357
clr!SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function+0x6c
clr!SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub+0x7a
...

How can I determine what GC is waiting for? Is it a normal for GC to wait in a middle of collection?

P.S. Background GC threads are also in a waiting state. I suppose they wait foreground GC to complete.

Comment: And what problem is this causing?

Comment: Do you know what GC mode it is using currently? There are... [quite a few](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx)

Comment: Yes it is using Background Server GC

Comment: Andy since Gen 0 collection happens once per 2 seconds and takes more than a second it causes all requests to be slowed down (since worker threads are suspended during GC).